# Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment

Tags: angular, routes, angular-ui-router

Hello I am new in angular 17 and I am trying to use routing to navigate from page to another

App.Component.htm

```
<nav class="flex justify-between p-4 bg-purple-900 text-white">
    <div>
        <a  routerLink="/">Books Shop</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a routerLink="/Cart">Cart</a>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="p-5">
    <router-outlet ></router-outlet>
</div>
```

App.Component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterLink, RouterLinkActive, RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BookComponent } from './books/book/book.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    standalone: true,
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrl: './app.component.css',
    imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, FormsModule,RouterLink, RouterLinkActive,BookComponent,CartComponent]
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'my-New-App';
}
```

App.Routes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BooksComponent } from './books/books.component';
import { CartComponent } from './cart/cart.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path:'', component:BooksComponent  },
    { path:'cart', component:CartComponent },
];

@NgModule({
imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
exports:[RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{

}
```

but when click on cart for example it give
`Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'Cart'`

I tried nothing      .

Comment: I believe `'cart' !== 'Cart'`; Can you try fixing this and come back if it still doesn't work ?

Comment: Yes it works, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it works by changing "/Cart" to "/cart"